# Creating Proper Authorization request using PHP curl

Tags: php, authorization, curl

I am given this as an example:

```
 Request example 1:
 POST /v1/token HTTP/1.1
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Accept: application/json
 grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=test&client_secret=abc123
```

I am using PHP/Curl to attempt this.

I have tried:

```
$url = "someUrl";
$ch = curl_init();

$username = "someUser";
$password = "somePass";

$post = json_encode(array(('grant_type'=>'client_credentials'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but get an error: "error":"unsupported_grant_type"

What is the correct format?

Comment: should i use stackoverflow?

Comment: My browser cut off the last part of your comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this worked:(if anyone cares to explain that would be good)

changing:

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
```

to:

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type=client_credentials");
```